# filtering the same starting value multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

hi i'm using logs insight to make aquery and i'm trying to filter the system filed @message multiple times, with the intention of filter the same starting value every time, i tried to make 3 separate values using fields and then filter each one of them, but when i filter one of then the other 2 get affected by the same filter as well, this is the query:

```
fields @logStream as stream, @message as ms1, @message as ms2, @message as ms3
| filter stream like /qt-/
| filter ms1 like /Message not yet played/
| filter ms2 like /INFO: Processing event message/
| filter ms3 like /Message already played/
| stats count(ms3) as n_messages by stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the filtering process for each alias by using the fields and filtering clauses independently.

```
fields @logStream as stream, 
       @message as ms1, 
       @message as ms2, 
       @message as ms3
| filter stream like /qt-/
| fields @logStream as stream, 
         @message as ms1
| filter ms1 like /Message not yet played/
| fields @logStream as stream, 
         @message as ms2
| filter ms2 like /INFO: Processing event message/
| fields @logStream as stream, 
         @message as ms3
| filter ms3 like /Message already played/
| stats count(ms3) as n_messages by stream
```

Comment: it gives me an error: Ephemeral field is already defined: stream. and after changing the differents fields names it doesn't work

Comment: i did some testing and if i filter the variable, and later retake it with another fields it comes already filtered

Comment: You can also try use `parse` command like this:


```fields @logStream, @message
| filter @logStream like /qt-/
| parse @message "Message not yet played" as ms1
| parse @message "INFO: Processing event message" as ms2
| parse @message "Message already played" as ms3
| stats count(ms3) as n_messages by @logStream```